# I can't shade smooth my curve/path 2.8

Tags: bezier-curves, path

I'm following a video on youtube "Creating braid in blender" and he shade smooths the curves around 2:40. My model is the exact same as his and when I have it selected I go up to object, and go down and click "shade smooth". Only it does nothing. It's ruining my braid and bothering me to no end.

Comment: you cant shade smooth a curve if its not corverted to a mesh first.

Comment: It stated off as a mesh and I converted to a curve. Well I'm following a tutorial and I've done everything the same as them. Their curve smooths when they hit shade smooth.

Comment: The video I'm watching was made over a year ago. Setting were probably different. I'm just move on.

Comment: yeah just after you finish your edits in the curve convert it to mesh and then you can smooth shade

Comment: That is false and wrong. You can certainly shade smooth a curve object, and you shouldn't be converting to mesh unless strictly needed, since it is a destructive process

Answer (score 2):

You certainly can **Shade Smooth Curve**.

1. In the **Transform** panel ("T" menu).
2. **Curve Data** tab under **Active Spline**.

If it is not working as it supposed for you, probably you have some issues with your **Curves**.

[image: final]